# How do i extract only pages that contain a specific word from a large ms-word document of 500 pages?

Tags: macros, extract, copy-paste

I need a way to separate the pages of a word document that contain the word "online" from the pages that do not. I can't figure out a way to do this efficiently without doing a search for the word and individually copying and pasting each specific page that contains the word to another document. I need a macro that can do this or maybe something simpler that I can't think of.

Answer (score 0):

The below link has macro to find a particular text (profane words in this case), you could modify and use the same macro for your text searching tasks:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112302/word-macro-to-find-profanity-and-create-a-list-of-occurences